# How to mention C:\Program Files in batchfile

Tags: batch-file

I need to invoke an exe file in C:\Program Files directory from a batch file.How can we mention the directory name "Program Files" in batch file.I am getting error like C:\Program not found.

I believe that % or ~ needs to be added in between but couldn't get it.Kindly assist.

Comment: I have tried Googling before posting. I have used terms like "how can we mention Program Files directory in batch file?" but couldn't get proper results.Thanks

Comment: Try searching for `cmd.exe how to specify a path with spaces`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Surround the script call with `""`, generally it's good practices to do so with filepath.

```
"C:\Program Files"
```

Although for this particular name you probably should use environment variable like this :

```
"%ProgramFiles%\batch.cmd"
```

or for 32 bits program on 64 bit windows :

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\batch.cmd"
```

Comment: better to use environment variables `"%ProgramFiles%"` and `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%"`

Comment: @DavidCandy Indeed, fixed.

Comment: Wow, never knew that `^` is an escape character in Windows. I've always thought that it's just ctrl+key. BTW in win 64 bit there's another environment variable to access 32-bit program files: `%ProgramW6432%`

Comment: C:\Program^ Files is the one which I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RameshJothimani If this answers the question please mark the answer as accepted using the green tick.

Comment: @RémiBenoit : Sure.I have just got one more issue.When I use it in my actual batch file as "start C:\Program^ Files\temp.exe" , I am getting error but it works fine when I use "E:\Program^ Files\temp.exe".Kindly suggest some solution.

Comment: Maybe `temp.exe` is located in the E: drive?

Comment: @RémiBenoit : The file exists in "C:\Program^ Files\temp.exe" I have metioned it as E:\ drive by mistake.Since there is a command Start before "C:\Program^ Files\temp.exe" , I am getting error.Kindly suggest some solution.

Comment: Ha, I didn't see the `start` function. What is the point of this function? If you just need to run `temp.exe` remove it.

Comment: @RameshJothimani: Instead of using escape characters, adding `"` around the path is more readable and is "standard" in passing paths in Windows. I've never seen a program using `^` to escape

Comment: If you need to specify many parameters before running the program such as priority, affinity... then call it with `start`. Otherwise, just use the filename, that's enough

Comment: Note that `start` is not directly interchangeable with using the filename: `start` without `wait` runs the program asynchronously with the rest of the batch file (instead of pausing until the program finishes); and if the exe cannot be found, `start` stops the batch file with a popup message.

Comment: @RameshJothimani, I would never recommend escaping special characters in paths.  The accepted best practice is to use quotes around file paths with spaces and special characters.

Answer (score 8):

On my pc I need to do the following:

```
@echo off
start C:\"Program Files (x86)\VirtualDJ\virtualdj_pro.exe" 
start C:\toolbetech\TBETECH\"Your Toolbar.exe"
exit
```

Comment: How to add parameters say from your example, virtualdj_pro.exe with paramameters  -PACKAGENAME ABCSync?

Answer (score 3):

I use in my batch files - `c:\progra~2\` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\` and it works.

Comment: And do you know why it works? How does this solve OPs problem?

Comment: It's much better to ask to run `dir /X c:\` once to get the shortened name, which indeed can work. But may also be ~1, or in theory any other number...

Comment: @RaZa74 It is a good practice to align your answers to what OP asks. Your answer would definitely have got some upvotes if you framed it correctly. Just saying ...

Answer (score 2):

> **Now that bash is out for windows 10**, if you want to access program files from bash, you can do it like so: `cd /mnt/c/Program\ Files`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue as you, although I was trying to use `start` to open Chrome  and using the file path. I used only `start chrome.exe` and it opened just fine. You may want to try to do the same with exe file. Using the file path may be unnecessary.

Here are some examples (using the file name you gave in a comment on another answer):

- Instead of `C:\Program^ Files\temp.exe` you can try `temp.exe`.
- Instead of `start C:\Program^ Files\temp.exe` you can try `start
  temp.exe`

Answer (score 0):

use this as somethink

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Nox/bin/nox_adb" install -r app.apk
```

where

```
"path_to_executable" commands_argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly with variables ,this worked for me ...

```
SET "VESTADIR=\\%TARGET%\C$\"Program Files (x86)"\Cassidian\VESTA"
```

Answer (score -4):

While createting the bat file, you can easly avoid the space. If you want to mentioned "program files "folder in batch file.

**Do following steps:**

**1.** Type `c:` then press enter

**2.** `cd program files`

**3.** `cd "choose your own folder name"`

then continue as you wish.

This way you can create batch file  and you can mention program files folder.